# (Social) inequality measure based on chi-square

Tags: chi-squared-test, diversity

Is there any social inequality measure for categorical or ordinal variables, based on a goodness of fit `chi squared test` (distance from an uniform distribution)?

Example: part of my data is unemployment rates by 4 age groups. I know that inequality is minimum if the rates are equal for the 4 age groups (uniform distribution), for example [0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04].

N.B. The sum of these rates is $\neq$ 1.

Comment: Can you explain your question more fully? What type of data do you have? What are you measuring?  What is your research question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a possibly useful general discussion of 'Diversity indexes' you might
want to look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diversity_index),
perhaps starting with the Simpson index
$$\lambda = \sum_{i=1}^R p_i^2,$$
where $R$ is the number of different 'types' of individuals and $p_i$ are
their respective proportions in the population.

For a large population, roughly speaking, $\lambda$ can be viewed as the
probability that two individuals randomly chosen from the population are of
the same 'type'. Thus, smaller $\lambda$ corresponds to greater diversity.

Comment: Please see my edits. I am not sure if with the Simpson index $\sum_{i=1}^R{p_i}$ has to be $=1$. Thank you for the link to 'Diversity indexes'.

Comment: In your unemployment example: conditionally on being unemployed, age groups are equally likely [.25,.25,.25,.25] and you could use the standard chi-squared test statistic for adherence to that _proper probability distribution_ (with probabilities summing to 1).

Comment: And the Simpson index also works in this case? Even if the unemployment rates are for example [0.04, 0.08, 0.16, 0.32]? In this case should I force (compute) the sum of probabilities to be 1 as in [0.066, 0.133, 0.267, 0.533]?

Comment: For the Simpson index, I think it would be $p_1 = p_2 =p_3=p_4 = 0.25,$ so that $\sum_{i=1}^4 p_i = 1.$

Comment: May be I have not been clear. In the case of inequality as 0.066 + 0.133 + 0.267 + 0.533 = 1. What I mean is that for using Simpson index the sum of $p_i$ must be 1. So in the case of unemployment rates (which have different denominators) and normally doesn't sum 1, I have to recalculate them dividing each one by the sum of rates. Is this so?

Comment: Don't have your data. And you've not made your objective clear. So can't answer precisely. // If the issue is unemployment, then look at all unemployed subjects and the proportion of them in each age group. That would be 'conditioning' on employment.

Comment: I am sorry. The "proportion of (unemployed subjects) in each age group" is precisely the unemployment rate. If these proportions for each of 4 age groups are [0.04, 0.08, 0.16, 0.32] they do not sum 1. My objective is to measure this diversity. Thank you again.

Comment: You want the proportion of all unemployed subjects who happen to be members of each age group. 'Condition on unemployment` means $P(G_i|\text{Unemployed}).$ Not $P(\text{Unemployed}|G_i).$ Not $P(\text{Unemployed}\cap G_i).$